# Radio button for each row data retrieve from database

Tags: php, html

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT sm01.SM01_01, sm01.SM01_03, sm13.SM13_02 = sm13.SM13_03 FROM "
    . "sm13 INNER JOIN sm01 on sm01.SM01_01 = sm13.SM13_03 WHERE sm13.SM13_02 = $id";
    $sql_run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $j = 0;
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql_run);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql_run) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_run)) {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $j = $j + 1; ?></th>
        <td class="text-left"><input type="hidden" class="form-control-plaintext" name="id_ahli[]" value="<?php echo $row['SM01_01']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?></td>
        <td><div class="form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="status"id="radio1<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>">Tidak</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="status" id="radio2<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>">Hadir</label>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

I success to retrieve the data but i got the problem with the radio button where I want each row the radio button is checked for the Tidak label

[The image of the problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oTQ0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code `name` attribute of radio button is same so only one radio will be set as selected .Instead change your code like below :

```
<tr>
    //other html code  //added here name_rowno 
     <td><div class="form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="status_<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>"id="radio1<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>">Tidak</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="status_<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>" id="radio2<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>">Hadir</label>
          </div></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I already done it and it works and now I have problem to pass the value as this form is used to update the database. I don't know how to pass the name as each row will have different name.

Comment: How does your data will get submitted using one form ?Also as you are passing `hidden` input i.e : `<?php echo $row['SM01_03']; ?>` you can simply concat `name__`(yourrowsmo33) to get required radio button values.